# Slow data receiving via QSerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I've got a problem with speed of reading recieved data from serial port. I am using QSerialPort class. I've confgured it right (set the same serial port options as these ones set on transmitter). In MainWindow constructor I've connected signal from QSerialPort to MainWindow's method (readData()) when I'm reading the raw data. It looks like:

```
MainWindow()
{
    std::shared_ptr<QSerialPort> serial; //don't aks me why shared_prt - it has to be shared_ptr, no other option.
    serial = std::shared_ptr<QSerialPort>(new QSeralPort)
    connect(serial.get(),SIGNAL( readyRead()),this,SLOT(readData())); 
}

void MainWindow::readData()
{
    QByteArray data = serial->readLine();
    qDebug() << data;
}
```

The data looks like: "s03445\n". Program reads and presents data correctly, but very, very slow (for example it prints "s3445"). Data are send with about 20 Hz frequency (400 samples - after that is one secand pause), but in my program data, are present with frequency about 3-4 Hz. It is also noteworthly that when I connect to my transmitter via simple serial port terminal (Hercules) I recieve data with full speed. What could be reason of that behaviour? What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Qt 5.2.1? I will assume it is Windows based on the serial terminal Hercules. Is it a native serial port, bluetooth, usb-serial dongle, etc? Can you reproduce it on other platforms, too? Do the command line writer and reader examples work properly for you?

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator 2.8.1 based on Qt 5.1.1. and yes, I did it on Windows 7. I can have a problem to reproduce it on the other platform, (maybe I could try on ubuntu 13.04 - but still it will be quite a bit problem). About command line - do you mean this one in qt - it worked well (but I still don't know what is about "writer and reader examples")?

Comment: I've just rewritten my code and in current conception it's works really good. The most important change: instead of readLine() I've used readAll() and returned value put in some buffer (from my research - only readAll() give us full speed retrievieng data rate). In the separated thread I implemented code for encampsulation of buffer. Now every thing work really good :)

Comment: This is great to hear, and my same experience switching to readall(). Were you able to still utilize the \n & \r characters to help parse out the data? or did you reference each bit token to access the data/parse to a variable? Thanks!